# Why does cpp.hint contain both __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When you create a new DLL project, Visual Studio adds a `cpp.hint` file with the following content:

```
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
```

**Question:**

Why does the file both include `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)`?

Shouldn't it be one or the other, but not both?

Comment: Usually you'll have a `#if` to pick between one and the other, so that a single header file works within the DLL itself and for code that wants to call your DLL.  What you have now should error out with a macro redefinition error.

Comment: The `cpp.hint` file isn't used for compilation. it's used to help the parser find things like function names and class names. Having two definitions isn't harmful (either replacement keeps the parser happy), though it does look weird. Even a blank definition `#define TEST_API` is enough to keep the parser on track. (Maybe the idea is that you keep one and delete the other, depending on whether your project provides the function or consumes it.)

Comment: Snippet should look like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-a-header-file-to-the-dll): `#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif`

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT [Hint files do not support `#ifdef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/hint-files?view=msvc-170#syntax).